# MonoDevelop is Removing My Reference to System.Drawing (Unity)

Tags: reference, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

In one of my scripts it is required that I reference System.Drawing. However it seems every time I start up the project and enter Mono it's removed the reference and I need to re-add it.

All my other references stay where they should be, any particular reason this may be happening or how I would prevent it?

Comment: Would it be possible to give some more information about this? I can't necessarily tell you what's happening off the top of my head but given more information I might be able to. Honestly, I haven't run into this problem myself though.

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Don't misuse it.

Answer (score 0):

Unity regenerates the .csproj.sln files automatically whenever the filesystem changes which will overwrite any change you have made to your .csproj.sln.

Unity uses information from the Unity project and the filesystem to do this so you have to use a method Unity understands for your changes to be preserved. For example, preprocessor flags have to be defined through the Unity project and assemblies have to be added via the filesystem.

I believe if you drop your dlls into ./Assets/Dlls then they will be included in the project. However, I suspect System.Drawing will not be supported because its an incompatible drawing library.